# How to ignore repeated sequential values in a database query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a huge postgres database that needs to be queried constantly. The dataset I'm quering has many repeated sequential values. Example:

```
3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ... 1,1,1,1,1,8
```

Is it possible, in case of a sequence of repeated values to return only the first and last records of that sequence? Example:

```
If the data is:
3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ... 1,1,1,1,1,8
The query result should be:
3,4,5,1*,1**,8

* first occurrence of "1"
** last occurrence of "1"
```

**Edit**:
The rows I'm selecting are composed of [value, created_at], ordered by created_at.
As I need to display this information in a chart it is important to get the first and last occurrence, the values in between can be ignored.

Comment: Are the sequences returned as rows or columns?

Comment: Is there a reason just getting the distinct values wouldn't work?

Comment: @ChristopheD rows, each row is composed of [value, created_at]

Comment: Assuming the rows are in order by `created_at`?

Comment: @DanielLyons As I need to display this information in a chart it is important to get the first and last occurrence, the values in between can be ignored

Comment: @harpo yes, rows are ordered by created_at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LAG and LEAD to do this fairly easily:

```
with T(n,created_at,bef,aft) as (
  select
    n,
    created_at,
    lag(n,1) over (order by created_at),
    lead(n,1) over (order by created_at)
  from your_table
)
  select
    n,
    created_at
  from T
  where bef is distinct from n
  or aft is distinct from n;
```

If the values of created_at are not unique, you should add a distinguishing column to the ORDER BY lists so the lag() and lead() expressions are deterministic.

Comment: Aargh. It should be IS DISTINCT FROM, not IS NOT DISTINCT FROM. I tested it on SQL Server, which doesn't have that feature... I'll fix it.